# Why I can not send URL as json element which is passed to the data attribute of ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api

I have and ajax request and I pass data to the data property like this:

```
var myData = { "Identifier": 12312312, 
               "Description": "description",
               "Name": "name", 
               "ImageUlr": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rob-sanders/hat/256/Hat-baseball-red-icon.png", 
               "Price": "price" };

$.support.cors = true;


$.ajax({ type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         url: myUrl + categoryId,
         data: JSON.stringify(myData),
         contentType: 'application/json',
         success: function (returnedData) {},
         error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {},
         processData: false,
         async: false
       });
```

And when it goes to the server (Web Api), the ImageUrl is null. Here is my server side:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostProduct ([FromBody] Product postedProduct, string categoryId)
{
   this.dbManager.PushNewProductInCategory(postedProduct, categoryId);
   return Ok();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to stringify the data, you should send it in json format only like below and that would work.

```
var myData = { "Identifier": 12312312, "Description": "description", "Name": "name", "ImageUrl": "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/rob-sanders/hat/256/Hat-baseball-red-icon.png", "Price": "price" };
```

$.support.cors = true;

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: myUrl + categoryId,
            data: myData,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (returnedData) {},
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {},
            processData: false,
            async: false
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I cant be 100% certain that this will fix your issue you do have a typo "ImageUlr"

Answer (score 0):

Your `data: JSON.stringify(myData)` should be `data:myData`, you should not `stringify` it as in `POST AJAX requests` the data should be a **valid** `object`.

Also their is a typo in `myData` `ImgUlr` should be `ImgUrl`